# Do something every 5 seconds and the code to stop it. (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I repeat a function `doSomething()` every 5 seconds.

I also need code that will make it stop doing it.

And code to on-the-fly adjust the frequency.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

setTimeout() will only launch the command once. In this case, setInterval() is your friend.

```
var iFrequency = 5000; // expressed in miliseconds
var myInterval = 0;

// STARTS and Resets the loop if any
function startLoop() {
    if(myInterval > 0) clearInterval(myInterval);  // stop
    myInterval = setInterval( "doSomething()", iFrequency );  // run
}

function doSomething()
{
    // (do something here)
}
```

from code...

```
<input type="button" onclick="iFrequency+=1000; startLoop(); return false;" 
       value="Add 1 second more to the interval" />
```

Comment: How do I adjust the frequency on-the-fly? And what code will stop setInterval()?

Comment: the frequency is the second argument of the function. See the link to the tutorial.

Comment: but how can I change the freq when the interval is in progress?

Comment: to modify the frequency on the fly, you would have to clear the interval and recreate it with the new frequency each time. Wrap all this in a helper function that deals with the setInterval/clearInterval control, function to which you pass the frequency as argument, and, why not, the function to execute.

Comment: eg.

0: starts..

1: timerchanged to 1 sec. <-- should exec here.

2: Doit();

Comment: done editing ... one method to call only, if there's any loop it will stop first and apply new frequency ... if first time, it only starts it. Much Simpler this way

Comment: There is no =+ operator... Perhaps you meant to use the += operator?

Comment: I think `myInterval = setInterval( "doSomething()", iFrequency );` ought to be `setInterval( doSomething, iFrequency );` – the quotes imply eval and setInterval should be passed a function.

Comment: Really time saver. I was trying to create a stop function for it an so far do not manage, Any idea how i can stop this function to run @pixeline ?

Answer (score 7):

Use

**[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setInterval)**

> Calls a function repeatedly, with a
>   fixed time delay between each call to
>   that function.

for repeated action and

**[clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval)**

> Cancels repeated action which was set
>   up using setInterval().

to stop that

Comment: Ok clearInterval stops it, but what about changing the frequency?

Comment: You can change the delay in the setInterval

Comment: but how can I change the freq when the interval is in progress?

Comment: @steven, perhaps u should clearInterval and create the new one with new time parameter

Answer (score 0):

You could use setTimeout() for this.

http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: how do I stop it? And how do I adjust the frequency on-the-fly?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var t; var timer_is_on=0; var timeout=5000;

function timedCount() {
  doSomeThing();
  t = setTimeout("timedCount()",timeout);
}

function doTimer() {
  if (!timer_is_on) {
    timer_is_on=1;
    timedCount();
  }
}

function stopCount() {
  clearTimeout(t);
  timer_is_on=0;
}
function changeFreq() {
   timeout = 2000;
}
</script>
```

Comment: nice. Close, doesn't change the frequency on the fly but I'm not sure if that's possible now.