# Program command to be called every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do something every 5 seconds and the code to stop it. (JQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542280/do-something-every-5-seconds-and-the-code-to-stop-it-jquery)

I have a gallery that i want to automatically run without me using it.

How can i run a script that calls this every 5 seconds or so on this http://www.meadmiracle.com/SlidingGalleryDemo1.htm

I need this to be called every 5 seconds or so bsaically so the gallery looks like it automatically scrolls.

```
$.galleryUtility.slideLeft( )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        setInterval( function(){
            $.galleryUtility.slideLeft() ;
        }, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

---

**Update**

In your specific case, you should add it right after you initialize the gallery.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('div.gallery img').slidingGallery(); // add it right after this line of you existing code
        setInterval( function(){
            $.galleryUtility.slideLeft() ;
        }, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

---

**Update 2**

To start stop the autoslide you will need to clear the interval, and to do so you need a reference to the returned value from the `setInterval` call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var autoSlideInterval;

    function start_autoslide(){
        autoSlideInterval = setInterval( function(){
            $.galleryUtility.slideLeft() ;
        }, 5000);
    }

    function stop_autoslide(){
        clearInterval( autoSlideInterval );
    }

    $(function() {
        $('div.gallery img').slidingGallery(); 
        start_autoslide();
    });

</script>
```

now when you want to star the auto-slide you call `start_autoslide();` and when you need to stop it you call `stop_autoslide();`

Comment: So do i enclose this in 

<script type='text/javascript'>

</script>

Comment: @mystycs, yes. And best to do it after the images have loaded.. updating answer..

Comment: @mystycs Yes, this is still javascript afterall.

Comment: Ah this is beautiful! But what if i click on the gallery during auto play? And i wish to go to another image it will keep auto playing? How can i clear this when i decide to actually click on them.

Comment: Same idea the guy gave below but im not sure how to implement that

Comment: @mystycs, you need to store the return value from the `setInterval` like this `var interval = setInterval(....);`and use `clearInterval` to stop it, like this `clearInterval( interval );`. the re-run the `setInterval` to start it.

Comment: Okay i think i get it let me try to implement this.

Comment: @mystycs, updated answer again with an explanation and code..

Comment: Okay is this the right idea ?

`<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var id = setInterval($(function() {
        $('div.gallery img').slidingGallery(); // add it right after this line of you existing code
        setInterval( function(){
            $.galleryUtility.slideLeft() ;
        }, 5000);)
</script>`

Comment: To call functions i use `<script type="text/javascript">
function functionName()

</script>` right?

Comment: @mystycs, update 2 (*re-updated*) is a complete setup of your existing code with my code.. (*the **`function`** keyword is to define a function, not to call it*)

Comment: Wow you are such a great help. So bsaically i should make it when i click on one of these images i turn off auto by calling the function right?

Comment: Ah okay i just am not sure hot to make it when i click on a image that i turn off auto otherwise it just keeps going

Comment: Okay thank you so much right now you helped me out! I will find ym way here! I am a c++ guy havent learned java yet but seems similair haha

Comment: @mystycs. Have fun :) [(*btw javascript is not java*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/About_JavaScript)

Comment: Oh yes lmfao i get confused -__-

Answer (score 1):

```
var id = setInterval(function ()
{
    $.galleryUtility.slideLeft(); 
}, 5000);
```

Every 5 seconds this will be called. If you need to have it stop at some point or condition then called the following:

```
clearInterval(id); //You must pass in the id that was returned after calling setInterval()
```

Clarification:

When you call `setInterval()` it actually returns an integer ID value. You store this and pass it into `clearInterval(**id goes here**)` to stop any further executions of that code.

Comment: Wait wait i need that as well. how exactly do i make it so that if i click on the gallery it will stop the auto? This is something good.

Comment: @mystycs Store the id it returns. Then when they click on the gallery, call `clearInterval(id)` and pass in the stored id.

Comment: Let me try this im new to javascript